# get id number of current inserted row in transaction mysql

Tags: php, mysql

As far as mysql_insert_id function in php would be buggy if you have so much insert query flows to table.

```
$r = mysql_query('insert query');
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

In above example you suppose id is 4097 while php process mysql_insert_id may return 4098 or 4099. This different is because of mysql_insert_id will return the last row of table, not last row of inserted in this connection.

I need to find a solution that get last id of the current insert id, not table.

I always coded such below:

```
$microtime = microtime(true)
$r = mysql_query('insert into table (time,value1,value2,value3) VALUE ($microtime,$val1,$val2,$val3));
$id = mysql_query('select from table where time="$microtime" AND value1=$val1 AND $value2=$val2 AND $value3=$val3);
```

I need to select like this because may even found 2 or 3 rows in same micro time! This will cause decrease of speed site because selecting by this criteria will not have enough performance.

So I looking a way that have more performance. I am open to hear your suggestion or solution.

Comment: If this is an option, try to migrate to different database - PostgreSQL or Oracle has sequences. You select id from sequence and then insert it with row (without auto increment)

Comment: `mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query`
`Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT). `

Comment: Hi, @li-on the script is written in php/mysql and I have no enough time to migrate it to another option.

Comment: Note:

note:Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the value.
This is published by PHP documentation a little below your source that you got the explanation of mysql_insert_id

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) says:

> int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
>
> Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

Are you sure that the mysql_insert_id is buggy ?

Are you sure that your column is AUTO_INCREMENT?

Do you have more than one connection opened? If so, you need to provide the `$link_identifier` parameter.

Comment: Yes I already talked about it in a comment. Based on Experience and PHP Documentation this function would be buggy in some cases this is a note come from php.net

Comment: Note:

    Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the value.

    Note:

    The value of the MySQL SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() always contains the most recently generated AUTO_INCREMENT value, and is not reset between queries.

Comment: The comment in the doc means that for a single connection you need to call the mysql_insert_id just after the insert query. The value will be overwritten when for the same connection you do a other insert query.